# Include the homepage or not in breadcrumbs?

Tags: google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets, homepage, breadcrumbs

[According to the Google guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumbs#use_cases) for breadcrumbs using Schema.org markup the first breadcrumbs trail should NOT be the homepage.

I tried using this markup and using the first trail as the homepage and the results were showing a webpage in SERP like this:

> www.example.com > Home > Category > Page

"Home" was actually linked as the first trail.

But I see thousands of other websites using "Home" as the first trail in their breadcrumbs. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Didn't the first paragraph of your question answer it?

Are you going to follow the herd who have likely never heard about google's guidelines or are you going to follow the guidelines of the organisation you are hoping will list your site in a way they think is most effective?

Comment: Except that G likes to make the rules... like m1cr0$0f7 when they need to follow the rules. The tradition is that the entire path is reflected in the breadcrumb. Because G says don't do it, does not mean that we should all jump off the cliff like lemmings. G does this all the time and webmasters all over the globe lift a finger to express their gratitude. I personally would not give a rip what G says on this. It is something that they just need to get over. But that is just me. I still give you a +1. How many questions do we get when the answer is, If you want to please G, then do it. Duh!

Comment: @closetnoc I agree with, but you know the golden rule. :P  And when you  think about it, SE isn't that much different.  Despite the way Q & A has 'always been done' SE has rules that from what I can tell, are being picked up by others.  It is mostly a 'good thing'

Comment: @Steve the thing is that this is only the case if you use the schema.org microdata from Google's examples. If you use data-vocabulary for example ... the correct way is the way with the homepage being the first page in the trail. Here is for example how Yoast uses it on one of his pages : https://yoast.com/cat/content-seo/ . I do not see the logic why Google treats this breadcrumb and displays it in SERP correctly yet with their example the SERP display is completley off

Comment: @Steve I am thinking of leaving the homage into the breadcrumb trail but do not mark it with the schema.org markup. What do you think ?

Comment: Personal preference...